Access to R.swift library resources generated inside the swift package from an Xcode project
My task is to bring R.swift into our own SPM, so that the code of app itself still has access to the generated Rswift resources.
Our package setup looks like this
let package = Package(
    name: "OwnPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "OwnPackage",
            targets: ["OwnPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift.git", exact: "7.5.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "OwnPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "RswiftLibrary", package: "R.swift")
            ],
            resources: [.process("Resources")],
            plugins: [.plugin(name: "RswiftGeneratePublicResources", package: "R.swift")]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "OwnPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["OwnPackage"]),
    ]
)

And inside our own package I created a file
import RswiftResources

public final class RSwiftTransfer {
    public static let rtext = R.string.localizable
    public static let rimage = R.image
}

And logically everything should work and I should have access to Rswift resources from the project code, but I get an error enter image description here. Please tell me how to solve this problem?
P.S.: I tried both by creating an instance with data inside the fields and through a singleton - the result is still an error.

The code to configure the package should have been written something like this:
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "OwnPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "OwnPackage",
            targets: ["OwnPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift.git", exact: "7.5.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "OwnPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "RswiftLibrary", package: "R.swift")
            ],
            plugins: [.plugin(name: "RswiftGeneratePublicResources", package: "R.swift")]
        )
    ]
)

Then create a file in the package, just write something like this in it:
public final class Generated {
    public static let rtext = R.string.localizable
    public static let rimage = R.image
}

After building the project, you just need to write import OwnPackage in the project files and you can access Generated.rtext and Generated.rimage and the resources inside them.
The files themselves should be placed in the Sources subfolder.enter image description here
